# How split string with nested strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have a string like this

`const str = "'a' 'b' 'c'"`

I want to split it and get in result array of strings

`const arr = str.split(" ")`

but in output I get:

`["'a'", "'b'", "'c'"]`

How can I get in output array without nested strings?

**Desired result**

`["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: Is there a possibility that one of those strings will have escaped `'` character? For example `["'doesn\'t' 'abc' 'mustn\'t'"]`

Comment: `Array.from(text.matchAll(/'([^']+)'/g), m => m[1])`

Comment: Or `Array.from(text.matchAll(/'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'/gs), m => m[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `replace` method by passing a *regex* expression in combination with `map` method by passing an *arrow function* as `argument`.

```js
const str = "'a' 'b' 'c'";
console.log(str.split(' ').map(el => el.replace(/'/g, "")));
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove `'` from above string using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and then split it:

```js
const str = "'a' 'b' 'c'";

const output = str.replace(/'/g, '').split(' ');

console.log(output);
```